# store.find() with relationship-object as parameter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I've got two models `Post.js` and `Category.js`

**Post.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  permalink: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category')
});

export default Post;
```

**Category.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  permalink: DS.attr('string'),
  posts: DS.hasMany('post',{async:true})
});
```

I'd like to retrieve all posts belonging to a category via 
`http://localhost:4200/<category_permalink>`.

I have trouble to retrieve the data in the route since this doesn't work because of the `category.permalink`.

**Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('post', { category.permalink: params.category });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `{ category.permalink: params.category }` is not a valid JSON. What you probably want to achieve is to have such an endpoint:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/post?category_permalink=:category_permalink`
```

Then, in Ember, you would rather use:

```
this.store.find('post', {
  category_permalink: params.category
});
```

and the response from the server should look more or less like that:

```
{
  "post": [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title",
    "body": "body",
    "permalink": "permalink",
    "category": 10
  }],
  "category": {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "name",
    "permalink": "c_permalink",
    "posts": [1,2,3]
  }
}
```